# Check OR operator in Reports

Tags: reporting

I have a report that filters conditions for different scenarios, so I need to add the filter check either of the conditions (`OR` operator) how can I check it ? Currently it shows (`AND`) which means it will filter for all the conditions rather individual conditions.

```
Corporate Title equals ""
AND
Role equals ""
AND
Operational Country equals ""
AND
Is Internal Contact equals "False"
```

so each of them should be checked individually with `OR` operator, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add filter logic to your report. You can do this by selecting it from the dropdown above your report from the customize screen. You can then change the operators to OR or add any advanced logic you need (e.g. (1 AND (2 OR 3)).

[image]